# Creating Fundamental Groups and How are they Described?

Tags: geometry

Im a math learner so this question may seem obvious.

Consider the fundamental group of a torus (we call this the object  $O(1)$). Suppose we have another torus and can glue it to the other torus to make a new object $O(2)$ with a fundamental group. What is the fundamental group of $O(2)$?

We repeat the process again gluing a torus to $O(2)$ to get an object  $O(3)$ that has a fundamental group.

We repeat the process again gluing a torus to $O(3)$ to get an object  $O(4)$ that has a fundamental group and so on.

What are the possible fundamental groups  $O(1)$, $O(2)$, $O(3)$, $O(4)$ and so on?

If we use another object instead of a torus then What are the possible fundamental groups  $O(1)$, $O(2)$, $O(3)$, $O(4)$ and so on?

If we use a random object each time instead of a torus (but it can be a torus) then what are the possible fundamental groups  $O(1)$, $O(2)$, $O(3)$, $O(4)$ and so on?

I'd love to know the answers.

Comment: Look up "van Kampen theorem".

Comment: Think about loops going in different directions and how they relate.